# How can I add multiple Search Engines to choose from in Chrome Enterprise?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, google-chrome, search-engine

In Chrome Enterprise you can specify the default search engine via GPO, and with the `DefaultSearchProviderEnabled` option you can prevent the users from overriding or changing that default search engine.
 
Now, is it possible to add another search engine so the users can choose one out of the two (and only out of these two)?